# Picture puzzle effect

Tags: color, vector

I want to convert a vectorized image into a picture puzzle as entertainment for children (see [example of a cat picture puzzle](https://www.coloring-page.net/activity/picture-puzzle.html)).

Essentially, the procedure would be:
- for all areas larger than a threshold, break them into a partition of areas smaller than the threshold, and with the same color
- remove the fill color and add a symbol corresponding to it
- add a caption with the association of symbol to color (probably by hand)

Then, when children color the image, the original picture would appear.

Is that possible in Illustrator, Photoshop, or the like?

**Update**: Here is the original photo:

[image: Original photo]

From this photo, I drew the following picture puzzle by hand:

[image: Hand-drawn picture puzzle]

I also converted the photo into a vector drawing with 12 colors:

[image: Vector drawing]

After cleaning up the colors in the vector drawing, can I automatically created a picture puzzle like the one drawn by hand?

Comment: If you are able to clean the image, you can try to apply a [Voronoi pattern](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Extensions-GenerateFromPath.html) to the elements (something like [this process](https://blog.bonnieeisenman.com/projects/clojure-puzzles/), but done by hand).